# Topological applications of $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{t}$

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, gn.general-topology, forcing, infinite-combinatorics

I'm working on the Malliaris-Shelah's recent result of $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{t}$, but I'm more interested in what possible topological applications can derivate from this equality.

Searching in several textbooks and articles, seems that there is no non-trivial application of this result yet (i.e. all the applications (until now) that I have found are obtained just changing the cardinals: so, if $\mathfrak{p}$ has some topological property, then $\mathfrak{t}$ also has it).

So, my question is: are there any interesting consequence of $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{t}$ in Topology?

Comment: The paper (https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d7c3/3c8d61111ffe524d25e8dcc1ff3d2f72e5f9.pdf of Alas and Wilson contains some interesting topological applications of the small uncountable cardinals $\mathfrak p$ and $\mathfrak t$ and those applications differ for those (eventually equal) cardinals $\mathfrak p=\mathfrak t$.

Comment: It's an interesting paper, but mybe my question wasn't clear enough. What I want to know is if somebody has found an application like this: "if $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{t}$, then (something)". There are several topological applications derivated from the equality of a pair of these cardinals, e.g. Kojman-Shelah showed that $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{c}$ implies the existence of a van der Waerden space that is not a Hindman space. These are the applications I'm trying to find